# Proving Lebesgue integrability of a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a simple function such that \begin{equation} |u(x)|\le\frac{x^2}{1+|x|^3}\end{equation} for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $u$ is Lebesgue integrable.

My attempt: Note that $f(x):=\frac{x^2}{1+|x|^3}$ is measurable as the ratio of two measurable functions. Moreover, $|u(x)|\le f(x)$ and by the dominance principle $u(x)$ is integrable as it is simple and bounded above so its integral will be finite. This is sufficient for integrability. Is this correct?

Comment: Though bounded (and even tending to $0$), $f$ is not integrable at $\pm\infty.$

Comment: @AnneBauval but $u$ is simple so can only take finitely many values; does this resolve that issue?

Comment: Yes it does, since the support of $u$ will then be bounded. I think your title should rather be: "Proving Lebesgue integrability of a simple function which tends to $0$ at infinity".

Comment: Can we use dominance principle in addition to the fact there are only finitely many values? or can we just not use dominance at all here

Comment: if $\phi$ is a nonnegative Lebesgue integrable function and $f$ a measurable function such that $|f(x)|\le \phi(x)$ for almost all $x$ then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable

Comment: You cannot apply this to $f=u$
 and $\phi(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+|x|^3}$
 because (as pointed in my first comment where it was named $f$ like in your post) the latter is not integrable. I think your title should rather be: "Proving that if a simple function tends to $0$
 at infinity then its support is bounded".

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $u=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}c_j\chi_{E_j}$ with $c _j \neq 0$ and $E_j$'s disjoint. Each $E_j$ is a bounded set: Otherwise,  $0< |c_j|\leq \frac {x_i^{2}}{1+|x_i|^{3}} \to 0$  along a sequence $(x_i)$ in $E_j$ tending to $\pm \infty$, a contradiction. Hence,  $u$ is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, let $u$ be a measurable function such that
$$\lim_{\pm\infty}u=0\quad\text{and}\quad m{\bf1}_E\le|u|\le M{\bf1}_E$$
for some measurable set $E$ and positive constants $m,M.$
Since $\lim_{\pm\infty}|u|=0<m,$ there exists a constant $A$ such that for all $x\in\Bbb R,$
$$|x|>A\implies|u(x)|<m.$$
For such an $A$, we have $E\subseteq[-A,A]$ and
$$\int|u|\,d\lambda\le M\,\lambda(E)\le2AM<\infty$$
hence $u$ is integrable.